# Jquery.cascade plugin change the format of the Ajax URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, cascade, dropbox

I'm using the [jQuery.Cascade](http://devlicio.us/blogs/mike_nichols/archive/2008/05/25/jquery-cascade-cascading-values-from-forms.aspx) plugin in my Asp.Net MVC application.  I've got it all working in a manner as follows:

```
jQuery("#CompareModelList").cascade("#CompareManufacturerList", {
                ajax: { url: '/Home/Models' },
                template: commonTemplate,
                match: function (selectedValue) { return this.ManufacturerId == selectedValue;},
            });
```

However, when this fires it calls the action in my controller via the following request:

```
http://localhost/Home/Models?val=50
```

What I would prefer is:

```
http://localhost/Home/Models/50
```

Now in the [examples](http://dev.chayachronicles.com/jquery/cascade/index.html) provided there is the following comment:

> Passes selected value of parent select
>   to url as 'val=', but accepts the full
>   ajax options hash so you can append
>   other data as well

So I'm presuming what I wish to achieve is possible - but as a newcommer to jQuery and Ajax I'm at a loss as to how to do this.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello,

Did you solve this problem?
I am having the same problem and not able to solve it.

Thanks,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cascade plugin is creating the default AJAX options (example: http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Options) which are:

```
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) { $this.trigger("updateList", [json]); },
    data: $.extend(_ajax.data,ajax.data,{ val: opt.getParentValue(parent) })
```

In other words, change the line:

`ajax: { url: '/Home/Models' }`

to

`ajax: { url: '/Home/Models/' + jQuery( '#CompareManufacturerList' ).val() }`

instead.

Comment: I think I see where you are coming from.  Only problem is this seems to leave the ?val=xx on the end.  Also it's not using the id from the selected dropbox entry, but the last dropbox entry.  I presume I have to find a way to tell it to use the selectedvalue

Comment: Also doesn't appear to work if  I am cascading multiple dropdowns.  I'm off back to the drawing board :(